# remove sublist from a single list of list python

Tags: python, list, subset

I have gone through [Removing sublists from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209786/removing-sublists-from-a-list-of-lists), but it didn't work for my case when I extend it for my dataset. Hence posting a new question.

```
list1=[['A,C,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
['A,B,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
['B,C,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
['A,B,C,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
['A', 'Z', 'hello'],
['A,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
['B,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
['A,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
['A,B,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
['H,I,J,K', 'Z', 'hello'],
['H,K', 'Z', 'hello'],
['H,L', 'Z', 'hello'],
['I,J,K,L', 'Z', 'hello'],
['H,I,J,K,L', 'Z', 'hello'],
['B,C,D','Z','hi'],
['A,D,C,B','Z','hi']]
```

I want to remove few elements and posting the desired output below:

```
**Output**
[['A,B,C,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
 ['A,B,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
 ['H,I,J,K,L', 'Z', 'hello'],
 ['A,D,C,B','Z','hi']]
```

I have tried with the code below:

```
sets = [set(l) for l in lists]
new_list = [l for l,s in zip(lists, sets) if not any(s < other for other in sets)]
```

Comment: Every list in list is sublist.On what basis you want to remove.

Comment: Yes @ PySaad, I think we have to figure out the pattern from the output and remove them

Comment: @pc_pyr what py is asking is that on what basis you want to remove some list and keep some. What are the characterstics of the lists that need to be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to split all by `,` al the elements from your sublists than you can use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209786/removing-sublists-from-a-list-of-lists) you already have found:

```
st = [{i for e in l for i in e.split(',') } for l in list1]
[l for l, s in zip(list1, st) if not any(s < other for other in st)]
```

output:

```
[['A,B,C,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
 ['A,B,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
 ['H,I,J,K,L', 'Z', 'hello'],
 ['A,D,C,B', 'Z', 'hi']]
```

Comment: Thanks @kederrac, it works perfectly with the pattern, just a clarification please, when I add `[['E,F,G,H','T','welcome'],['A,E,H','T','welcome']]` in the list of list, in addition to the above logic, I want to pick only ['E,F,G,H','T','welcome'] and remove ['A,E,H','T','welcome']] because 'E,H' is already present in ['E,F,G,H','T','welcome']. Is there a way to achieve it..