# remove elements from a single list of list python based on pattern-mathing

Tags: python, list, subset

I have visited [Removing sublists from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209786/removing-sublists-from-a-list-of-lists), but it didn't work for my case when I extend it for my dataset. Hence posting a new question.

```
list1=[['A,C,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
['A,B,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
['B,C,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
['A,B,C,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
['A', 'Z', 'hello'],
['A,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
['B,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
['A,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
['A,B,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
['H,I,J,K', 'Z', 'hello'],
['H,K', 'Z', 'hello'],
['H,L', 'Z', 'hello'],
['I,J,K,L', 'Z', 'hello'],
['H,I,J,K,L', 'Z', 'hello'],
['B,C,D','Z','hi'],
['A,D,C,B','Z','hi'],
['E,F,G,H','T','welcome'],
['A,E,H','T','welcome']]
```

I want to remove few elements and posting the desired output below:

```
**Output**
[['A,B,C,D', 'Y', 'hello'],
 ['A,B,C', 'Z', 'hello'],
 ['H,I,J,K,L', 'Z', 'hello'],
 ['A,D,C,B','Z','hi'],
 ['E,F,G,H','T','welcome']]
```

I have tried with the code below:

```
sets = [set(l) for l in lists]
new_list = [l for l,s in zip(lists, sets) if not any(s < other for other in sets)]
```

Comment: you are removing `['A,E,H','T','welcome']` because `EH` is already in `['E,F,G,H','T','welcome']` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630304/remove-sublist-from-a-single-list-of-list-python/60631204#60631204)) but you are not applying the same rule to the other, you have to mention that you treat those with `welcome` differently

Comment: Please explain the logic after which you remove the entries. Seems unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your input and desired output it seems that you want to split the first element of each list on `","`. Right now they are comma-separated strings and as such the subset logic won't apply to them. So you could do:

```
sets = [set(l[0].split(',')) | set(l[1:]) for l in lists]
```